# pytest: Mark on test class overrides same mark on test function

Tags: automated-tests, pytest

I'm using pytest.mark to give my tests kwargs. However, if I use the same mark on both the class and a test within the class, the class's mark overrides the mark on the function when the same kwargs are used for both.

```
import pytest

animal = pytest.mark.animal


@animal(species='croc')  # Mark the class with a kwarg
class TestClass(object):

    @animal(species='hippo')  # Mark the function with new kwarg
    def test_function(self):
        pass


@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)  # Use a fixture to inspect my function
def animal_inspector(request):
    print request.function.animal.kwargs  # Show how the function object got marked


# prints {'species': 'croc'} but the function was marked with 'hippo'
```

Where'd my hippo go and how can I get him back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've been digging around in the pytest code and figured out why this is happening. The marks on the functions are applied to the function at import time but the class and module level marks don't get applied on the function level until test collection. Function marks happen first and add their kwargs to the function. Then class marks overwrite any same kwargs and module marks further overwrite any matching kwargs.

My solution was to simply create my own modified MarkDecorator that filters kwargs before they are added to the marks. Basically, whatever kwarg values get set first (which seems to always be by a function decorator) will always be the value on the mark. Ideally I think this functionality should be added in the MarkInfo class but since my code wasn't creating instances of that I went with what I *was* creating instances of: MarkDecorator. Note that I only change two lines from the source code (the bits about keys_to_add).

```
from _pytest.mark import istestfunc, MarkInfo
import inspect


class TestMarker(object):  # Modified MarkDecorator class
    def __init__(self, name, args=None, kwargs=None):
        self.name = name
        self.args = args or ()
        self.kwargs = kwargs or {}

    @property
    def markname(self):
        return self.name # for backward-compat (2.4.1 had this attr)

    def __repr__(self):
        d = self.__dict__.copy()
        name = d.pop('name')
        return "<MarkDecorator %r %r>" % (name, d)

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """ if passed a single callable argument: decorate it with mark info.
            otherwise add *args/**kwargs in-place to mark information. """
        if args and not kwargs:
            func = args[0]
            is_class = inspect.isclass(func)
            if len(args) == 1 and (istestfunc(func) or is_class):
                if is_class:
                    if hasattr(func, 'pytestmark'):
                        mark_list = func.pytestmark
                        if not isinstance(mark_list, list):
                            mark_list = [mark_list]
                        mark_list = mark_list + [self]
                        func.pytestmark = mark_list
                    else:
                        func.pytestmark = [self]
                else:
                    holder = getattr(func, self.name, None)
                    if holder is None:
                        holder = MarkInfo(
                            self.name, self.args, self.kwargs
                        )
                        setattr(func, self.name, holder)
                    else:
                        # Don't set kwargs that already exist on the mark
                        keys_to_add = {key: value for key, value in self.kwargs.items() if key not in holder.kwargs}
                        holder.add(self.args, keys_to_add)
                return func
        kw = self.kwargs.copy()
        kw.update(kwargs)
        args = self.args + args
        return self.__class__(self.name, args=args, kwargs=kw)


# Create my Mark instance. Note my modified mark class must be imported to be used
animal = TestMarker(name='animal')

# Apply it to class and function
@animal(species='croc')  # Mark the class with a kwarg
class TestClass(object):

    @animal(species='hippo')  # Mark the function with new kwarg
    def test_function(self):
        pass

# Now prints {'species': 'hippo'}  Yay!
```

Answer (score 0):

There are unfortunately various [pytest bugs related to this](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+markers), I'm guessing you're running into one of them. The ones I found are related to subclassing which you don't do there though.